# iOS - Resizable images' fixed part settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode6

When using iOS resizable images, I have understood that the part of the image which extends is automatically determined (am I right?).

But then, it is possible to change the width of the 'fixed' part of the image ?

For example, is it possible to set broader '**left**' and '**right**' part in this picture :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [resizableImageWithCapInsets:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:) method of `UIImage`.

Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605514/how-to-use-uiimage-resizableimagewithcapinsets) on how to use it.